# MVC 3 project working fine but show my Visual studio show me that Viewbag is not found in current context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2013

I have a MVC 3 project and we have running it fine in Visual Studio 2010 & 2012. Since we move to 2013 it's showing us error.

```
Error   5   The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context    c:\workspace\project\xyz.cshtml 4   5   EnyaCMS
```

Their is no problem with ViewBag. I debug the project and it's work fine in Chrome browser.
Another problem is

```
Error   10  'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Partial' and no extension method 'Partial' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\workspace\another\index.cshtml   33  7
```

Someone tell me how to fix the issue. I thing the project have no issue since its' work fine in browser. How I can include the reference of ViewBag and other issue in my project's views.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem the other day with VS 2013 after I tried to upgrade an MVC project.

The problem occurred because the new VS project was set to an incompatible version of the .Net Framework - I think, by default, it was set to v4.0, and the nuget packages I was referencing were for newer .Net versions.

I changed the .Net target to v4.5.1, removed all my out of date nuget packages / problematic references, and re-referenced them all.

Comment: Thanks, I can't do this since our Server is running in .net 4 , MVC 3. Is their anything I can change that make it work.

Comment: You can apply the same principal - set your .Net target to .net 4, remove all your problem nuget packages / references, then re-add them. Nuget should detect the correct versions of the DLLs for you.